# Losing access to LAN devices when connected to a VPN

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, hyper-v, samba

I have an ubuntu VM running on Hyper-V which connects to a VPN service. When the VM is connected to the VPN I am unable to ping / connect to the host machine. Samba mounts won't get mapped, ping packets time out. 
What can I check in order to fix this?

Comment: Check the VPN policy, it can restrict the LAN access.

Answer (score 1):

It will be a setting enforced by your VPN provider. For example Cisco AnyClient VPN has such a setting that can effectively disconnect it from the LAN and force all traffic through the VPN.

I think it does it by removing all routes to the local LAN - you may be able to re-add the route and regain access to the LAN.

Unfortunately you don't say what VPN client you use and what VPN service. Is it some public one or a corporate VPN?

Comment: public VPN - Private Internet Access

Comment: @dross either it is enforced by the VPN provider or it's a setting in your VPN config. You'd better ask the VPN provider how to disable this setting - if it's a public VPN service they may even have it documented on their FAQ page?